# AngularJS event listener inside directive link function firing on each route change

Tags: angularjs

I have a route that has a custom directive. In it's link function, I listen for an event on the `window` object which calls a method on `scope`.

The problem is that if that each time the route that has this directive is redirected to, it will run the link function resulting in multiple event listeners being added to the `window` event.

How can I avoid this? I tried using the compile function, but it doesn't have access to scope so I can't call `scope.myMethod()` inside of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest that you use the $destroy event (see $destroy in [scope documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)) on your directive's scope and do the necessary cleanup there. Something like that :

```
angular.directive('MyDirective', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      .... //Code of your directive

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        console.log("destroy");
       //clean up - removeListeners
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas. Adding the listener in the compile phase (if at all possible) wouldn't prevent this right? I always have to call clean-up on $destroy?